# Why wont the program load up the next value, infinite loop

Tags: java, regex, loops, parsing

The output comes up as 1913 printed on the next 52 lines. how do I get it to load the next number and check if that is prime. If tell it to print after I parse it all the numbers are extracted and displayed fine.

I know its a logic error because I think I am writing my loops wrong

```
Scanner INPUT_TEXT = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\josep\\Downloads\\assignment2.csv")); //Create a Scanner Class and File Class to read a file from your computer.

INPUT_TEXT.useDelimiter(" "); //Divide DemoData.txt into several pieces by a space

while (INPUT_TEXT.hasNext()) {
    //Read each word
    String TempString = INPUT_TEXT.next();

    //Display all numbers.Eliminate comma, e.g., 1,200 -> 1200
    String temp1 = TempString.replaceAll("[\\,]", ""); //Create a String class temp1 that eliminates comma.
    String pattern1 = "[0-9]+"; //Create a String class pattern1 that stores the Regular Expression to match numbers.
    Pattern r1 = Pattern.compile(pattern1); //Create Pattern class to compile pattern1.
    Matcher m1 = r1.matcher(temp1); //Match each piece with the Regular Expression

    if (m1.find()) { //If a number is matched, print the number.
        int foo = Integer.parseInt(m1.group(0));
        result = foo;

        while (limit > 0) {

            //Assume the number if prime
            boolean isPrime = true; //Is the current number prime?

            // Test whether number is prime
            for (int divisor = 2; divisor <= foo / 2; divisor++) {

                if (foo % divisor == 0) { //If true, number is not prime
                    isPrime = false; //Set isPrime to false
                    break; // Exit the for loop
                }
            }
            if (isPrime) {
                System.out.println(result);
            }
            limit--;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `while(m1.find())` instead of `if(m1.find())` with some improvements:

```
while(m1.find()){
    result = Integer.parseInt(m1.group());

    //result not prime
    if( !(result % 2 == 0) ){
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

I don't know what your variable `limit` is used for thus I omitted it but feel free to put it where it belongs.